# android.overridePathCheck=true' is experimental and unsupported on 3.6 what should i do?

Tags: java, android-studio

Error:'android.overridePathCheck=true' is experimental and unsupported

Version:3.6

What should i do? Should i change something from the gradle.properties or is my file location the problem?

Thanks in advance